# "rand() % 7" always returns same result (but seed called exactly once)

Tags: c++, random

I'm only seeding rand() once, yet I have a sort of odd problem...
When I do,

```
int r = rand() % 7 + 1;
```

it returns 4 every time.

But if I replace that 7 with any other number, it works just fine.

Any idea why this is happening?

My full code's all cluttered right now, but here's basically what's giving me the problem:

```
int main() 
{
    srand(time(0));
    int r = rand() % 7 + 1;
    cout << r;
}
```

Even when I run it just like this, with nothing else, it still only returns 4.

P/S: For a little context, I'm working on a super simple amazons solitaire game that runs in the console (yes, I'm aware that console games aren't ideal. I just needed a simple amazons solitaire game I can play on my computer for whenever I don't have a deck of cards around.) which is why the random number has to be between 1 and 7.

PP/S: I'm using Xcode.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem with the code you've shown.  (Also, unrelated, but I can't help but [think of this](https://xkcd.com/221) ...)

Comment: @Rufflewind: I have the vaguest memory that there's a compiler (version?) that had a quirk that `rand()%7==4` very very often.  I think it was a specific version of xcode.  I'll try to remember...

Comment: well, you ARE seeding this with what is essentially a constant. try doing a couple rounds of `rand()` and `cout` in the same program and see if you get different values WITHIN that same instance of the program.

Comment: I'd just found [why does rand()%7 always return 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7866754/845092)

Comment: Haha, good ol' xkcd... 

As for running it a couple times within the program, I was getting 2 a lot, then I was getting 1 for the second output, every time I re ran the program.