# Repeated values from std::uniform_int_distribution

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I don't understand what's going on here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

unsigned number_in_range(unsigned, unsigned, default_random_engine);

int main()
{

    time_t now = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::now());

    default_random_engine rng(now);

    //
    // Print out 10 random numbers
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 100);
        cout << dist(rng) << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    //
    // Do the same thing, but get the numbers from `number_in_range()`
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << number_in_range(0, 100, rng) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

unsigned number_in_range(unsigned range_start, unsigned range_end, default_random_engine rng)
{
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(range_start, range_end);
    return dist(rng);
}
```

An example of the output of this code is:

```
45
21
10
3
54
18
23
72
68
27

68
68
68
68
68
68
68
68
68
68
```

`number_in_range()` works in exactly the same way as the code in my first for loop, and yet it spits out the same value over and over again. What's different about the `number_in_range()` version, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are copying the random engine instead of taking a reference to it. Hence, it always has the same internal state.

Try:

```
unsigned number_in_range(unsigned range_start, unsigned range_end, default_random_engine &rng)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: As a side note, I've noticed that the first number generated is always `45`. Is that normal? Should I always take one value and throw it away when I use the `std::default_random_engine`?

Comment: @anthropomorphic This is a pure seeding-issue. Don't throw away stuff without understanding PRNGs. Check your seed-input!

Comment: @anthropomorphic [and I guess that number changes every 20-ish minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730906/random-generates-same-number-in-linux-but-not-in-windows/32731387#32731387)

Comment: @T.C. Wow, it sure does. That was very enlightening, thanks.