# Performing fisher - yates shuffle directly in a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, random, shuffle

I have been trying, with no success, to perform a partial fisher-yates shuffle directly for the first N elements of a 2D array. I know I could transform the 2D array into a 1D array, perform the shuffle and then turn it back, but if possible I would like to avoid this.

The problem in my implementation is, I think although I have not proved it, that the last elements of each row of my array are not correctly shuffled. In fact, supposingI have a `m*n` array,of which the first `N` are equal to 1 and the rest `m*n - N` are equal to 0. When I perform my shuffle of the first `N` elements of the array, about 67% of the time the elements at the end of each row: `array[i][end]` are equal to 1, which seems to me to be too many times.

Here is my implementation along with a driver code that can be run to show what the problem is:

```
void swap(int **a, int i, int j, int iNew, int jNew) 
{
  int temp = a[i][j]; 
  a[i][j] = a[iNew][jNew]; 
  a[iNew][jNew] = temp;
}

void fisher_yates_shuffle(int n, int nbLines, int nbColumns, int **a) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nbLines; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nbColumns; j++)
        {
            swap(a, i, j, i+rand()%(nbLines-i), j+rand()%(nbColumns -j)); // swap element with random later element

            n--;

            if(n<=0)
                break;
        }
        if(n<=0)
            break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0, N = 10, k = 100000;
    srand(time(NULL));

    //Short example of a 5 by 5 array, with N = 10 first elements equal to 1
    //that need to to be shuffled among all of its elements.
    while(k > 0)
    {
        //allocate
        N = 10;
        int **a = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * 5);
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            a[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);

        //initialize
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                if(N > 0)
                    a[i][j] = 1;
                else
                    a[i][j] = 0;
                N--;
            }
        }

        //shuffle
        fisher_yates_shuffle(10, 5, 5, a);

        //count how many times the last element of each row is equal to 1.
        if(a[1][4] == 1)
            count1++;
        if(a[2][4] == 1)
            count2++;
        if(a[3][4] == 1)
            count3++;
        if(a[4][4] == 1)
            count4++;

        //destroy memory allocated.
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            free(a[i]);
        free(a);

        k--;
    }

    //print approximate results.
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", (count1 * 100)/100000, (count2 * 100)/100000, (count3 * 100)/100000, (count4 * 100/100000));

    return 0;
}
```

I know it doesn't look very good and there must be a more efficient way of doing it. Maybe there is a different, equally efficient algorithm to shuffle the first N elements of a 2D array like that?

Comment: Apparently `a` is an array of pointers, but you should clarify that by [edit]ing the question. Also, it would help to see what the `swap` function does. In summary, this question needs a [mcve].

Comment: I didn't think it made any difference for my question. As far as the way to approach the algorithm is concerned.

Comment: Role of `int n` unclear.  I'd expect `n` to be reset each `for (int i = 0; i < nbLines; i++)` iteration.

Comment: Given the implementation in your snippet, you could just use a plain array of n*m elements. BTW, have you properly used `srand`, somewhere in your code?

Comment: Instead of rand(), which produces randoms in range 0..RAND_MAX, and modulo operator, which does not provide even distribution, you should use better random function and better distribution, like those from `<random>` header, but for C instead for C++.

Comment: I editted the answer to show a quick a example of the problem. @Dialecticus I don't really see how rand could be the problem, in my opinion the choice of indexes that can be swapped is the issue. Since when I reach the end of a row, this element can only be swapped with the other elements that are in the same column (the last one).

Comment: @Dialecticus Given that the number of lines is 5 and that `RAND_MAX` is likely something like `2147483647`, I'd bet quite a sum that the modulo operator doesn't introduce any measurable problems with the distribution.

Comment: @AndrewHenle oh? try [`rand() % 7`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7866754/1553090) then.

Comment: Suggestion: put a `printf` on the first line of the `swap` function and print the four indexes that were passed to the function.

Comment: @paddy What's your point?  A poor `rand()` implementation produces poor results?  Note that even your example doesn't effect the *distribution* of results after the modulo operator.

Comment: @user3386109 Forgot to add another break outside of the first loop, this is why the indexes are not correct, I will edit it now and you could check again, the problem is that when j = 4 jNew = 4 necessarily.This kind of shuffle usually only ignores the items already shuffled in each iteration, but the way I implement for a 2D array, it ignores the items shuffled plus the whole column of all the items before the current one. This is the problem.

Comment: If you take out the 2 `if(n<=0)
                break;` from `fisher_yates_shuffle()`, does it work as desired?  The point being: use of `n` is distorting the shuffle.

Comment: @chux Not really, it just continues by unnecessarily shuffling random elements. Maybe it decreases somewhat the probability of an end row element being equal to 1 if said end row element is located after the Nth element of the array. However end row elements that are before that continue to have the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding my previous comment, you could shuffle your "array" in a single loop:

```
void fisher_yates_shuffle(int n, int nbLines, int nbColumns, int **a) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int j = i + rand() % (nbLines * nbColumns - i);
        swap(a, i / nbColumns, i % nbColumns, j / nbColumns, j % nbColumns); 
    }
}
```

Note that there are far better ways to implement and pass around a matrix in C and that your swap function should return `void`, not `int`.

Comment: This works perfectly, random positions get values of 1 with more or less the same probability. My "array" shuffle works now, thanks. I would also appreciate it if you could explain in more detail your comment about how I could pass my matrix into my function more efficiently

Comment: @Desperados See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays It's a long Q&A, but it's worth reading.

Comment: I think indexes (i and j) have to be divides by nbColumns so that the algorithm may be applicable to 'arrays' that are not square (n by n). I think my observation is correct, maybe you want to consider editing your answer or explaining to me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Desperados Yes, you are correct. Good catch, thanks.