# My result is not truly random; How can I fix this?

Tags: c++

```
float genData(int low, int high);
    
int main(){
    srand(time(0)); 
    float num = genData(40, 100);
    cout << fixed << left << setprecision(2) << num << endl;
            return 0;
}
        
float genData(int low, int high) {
    low *= 100;
    high *= 100 + 1;
    int rnd = rand() % (high - low) + low;
    float newRand;
    newRand = (float) rnd / 100;
    return newRand;
}
```

I'm expecting a random number between 40 and 100 inclusively with two decimal places.
eg: 69.69, 42.00

What I get is the same number with different decimal values, slowly increasing every time I run the program.

Comment: @Chris I have in the main function, is that not good enough?

Comment: @phuclv I have a prototype, its on the first line.

Comment: C++ provides [Pseudo-random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) (see example on page) See also [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) and [std::uniform_real_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)

Comment: at first glance I can't spot anything wrong with your code. It could be the quality of `rand`. Use C++11 random library instead.

Comment: @t1231 sorry, I glossed over that. What platform are you on? Many have notoriously bad `rand` implementation like [the one in macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7866754/995714)

Comment: https://ideone.com/QvsnxX some random linux is fine. so i guess this is an environment issue
what libc do you use?

Comment: I am on windows 10 using Clion

Comment: @BarmakShemirani where would I use another rand()?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani my problem is solved, thank you!!

Comment: You also have additional range problem, see the answers.

Comment: "What I get is the same number with different decimal values, slowly increasing every time I run the program." is an artifact of 1) Using `time()` to initialize 2) a terrible `srand()/rand()` implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Wrong range**

`int rnd = rand() % (high - low) + low;` does not generate the right range.

```
float genData(int low, int high) {
  low *= 100;
  // high *= 100 + 1;
  high = high*100 + 1;
```

---

> expecting a random number between 40 and 100 inclusively with two decimal places. eg: 69.69, 42.00

That is [40.00 ... 100.00] or 10000-4000+1 different values

```
int rnd = rand() % (100*(high - low) + 1) + low*100;
float frnd = rnd/100.0f;
```

---

**`rand()` weak here when `RAND_MAX` is small**

With `RAND_MAX == 32767`, `int rnd = rand() % (high - low) + low;` is like `[0... 32767] % 6001 + 40000`.  `[0... 32767] % 6001` does not provide a very uniform distribution.  Some values coming up 6 times and others 7-ish.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `<random>` header for that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

float getData(int const low, int const high) {
  thread_local auto engine = std::mt19937{ std::random_device{}() };

  auto dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>{ low * 100, high * 100 };

  return dist(engine) / 100.0f;
}

int main() {
  for (auto i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
    std::cout << getData(40, 100) << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: `uniform_real_distribution(a,b)` is a uniformly distributed on the interval [a, b). 
 100.00 is not generated so almost meets "random number between 40 and 100 inclusively".  Likely close enough for OP's needs it the result is rounded to nearest 0.01 per the usual `float` limitaitons.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica See if this one is better

Comment: Ayxan, It comes down to "random number between 40 and 100 inclusively with two decimal places", that is 6001 different values and how close to that OP really wants.  This answer (low, high) or (low,next(high)) both 1) get many values between the xx.xx values and 2 ) With a rounded to nearest 0.01, do not get the end values with same uniformity as the others.  Of course 2 decimal place values are not truly possible with `float`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I see what you mean. Thank you for the feedback. Please see if this update is better.

Comment: Maybe `high * 100` --> `high * 100 + 1` to catch 100.00?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica for [uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) the range is always inclusive because otherwise how would you get INT_MAX or ULLONG_MAX

Comment: Hmm: [not upper inclusive](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution), [upper inclusive](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/).  I'll have to dig up the C++ spec.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica *real* version is not inclusive, *int* version is inclusive.

Comment: Ayxan [Yes](http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3twuvz).  LSNED "A `uniform_int_distribution` random number distribution produces random integers i, a <= i <= b, distributed according to the constant discrete probability function"  C++ 26.5.8.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++ 11 you can use better random number generators that will give you diversity in the generated numbers in addition to being a lot faster.

Quick Example:

```
#include <random> // The header for the generators.
#include <ctime> // To seed the generator.
 
// Generating random numbers with C++11's random requires an engine and a distribution.
mt19937_64 rng(seed);
// For instance, we will create a uniform distribution for integers in the (low, high) range:
uniform_int_distribution<int> unii(low, high);
// Show the random number
cout << unii(rng) << ' ';
```

You can follow this article for more explanation from [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/61587).

Comment: Considering the question asks for a " number with two decimal places", `uniform_int_distribution` on its own is insufficient. But throw in a `/100.0` and you get two decimal places out. Of course, that will also require a `*100` for the range.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was showing how can he get a better random number then, he can do any needed processing.
Thanks for your note.